# Restfull Services org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, rest

I have an Angular Client; its Post data to java Rest Api. When I try to send String or integer data there is no any issue. but when I try to send List its gave an error something like;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D5qU.jpg)

> StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

and my Java Api

> ```
> @POST
> @Path("/senddata")
> @Produces("application/json")
> public String sendData(List<Data> model) throws Exception {
>     System.out.println("model : " + model);
> ```

```
    return "OK";
}
```

my Request from Angularjs

> ```
>    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/Project/webresources/json/product/senddata', postData1, {
>       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
>     });
> ```

my Character Encoding Class

```
@WebFilter("*.xhtml")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getCharacterEncoding();
        response.getCharacterEncoding();
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a wrapper object for your List and use that in your parameter list;

```
public class DataWrapper { 
    private List<Data> dataList;
...
}  


@POST
@Path("/senddata")
@Produces("application/json")
public String sendData(DataWrapper data) throws Exception {
...
```

Or add the @RequestParam(value="model") annotation to your existing parameter.

```
public String sendData(@RequestParam(value="model") List<Data> model) throws Exception
```

Comment: your answer would be more helpful if you updated it with an example of how to implement your suggestions.

Comment: I agree with @devlin